# \subparagraph{} equivalent in html

Tags: html, latex, paragraph, equivalent

I have my habits with LaTeX, then in HTML I don’t know which element can replace the LaTeX’s `\subparagraph{}` command. `<br />` isn’t a good idea because it is the equivalent of the blank line in LaTeX. I can create a special class “subparagraph” but before I want to know if HTML didn’t have a similar element.

The `\subparagrahp{}` LaTeX’s command is something between the paragraph and the HTML’s `<br />` element. [Overapi](http://overapi.com/html/) didn’t tell me more :/

Someone have any idea please?

Comment: if I understand it correctly (don't know LaTeX), then this creates a sub section. you can do that with nested <div> or <p> tags. It you're doing this to get visual indentation you can use the margin and/or padding css styles

Comment: I am not searching a way to have an indentation, I know how to do it with css ☺ I explain you : I translate a LaTeX document to HTML. In LaTeX I have a big `\paragraph{}` area (in LaTeX we name that an “environment”) containing many \**sub**paragraph{} environment.
I translate the `\paragraph{}` ton `<p>` but I don’t know how can I translate the `subparagraph{}`.
In LaTeX the `subparagraph{}` command make a top and bottom margin a little bit smaller than `paragraph{}`. If I translate this tow command to a same HTML element I will have a leak of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `div` element as the paragraph subsitute and `p` elements as subparagraphs, with additional class for styling, this could represent your LaTeX document structure.

```
\paragraph{Introfoo}
Introduction lorem lorem

  \subparagraph*{}
  Foobar lorem impsum ugh

  \subparagraph*{}
  Foobar lorem impsum ugh
```

would translate to:
The `h3` tag is just a suggestion, the level depends on your other structure around this.

```
<div class="paragraph">
  <h3 class="paragraph">Introfoo</h3>
  <p class="paragraph">    
    Introduction lorem lorem
  </p>
  <p class="subparagraph">
    Foobar lorem impsum ugh 1
  </p>

  <p class="subparagraph">
    Foobar lorem impsum ugh 2
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this way I final use. I what be sure that any other way is best than this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX' `\paragraph` is a heading element, the next-to-smallest one, so I'd map it to `<h5>`, leaving `<h6>` for subparagraphs, and use CSS to give them `display:inline-block` (run-in headers) and appropriate other styling as desired. This will leavel h1-h4 for title-and-or-chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection.