# Literal HTML markup doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to use literal HTML markup in doxygen. By literal i mean

> I want this tag here and do not touch it

Background: I want to have this[1] in my documentation, but doing so requires a custom div box, and doxygen breaks it.

[1] [\subparagraph{} equivalent in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246456/subparagraph-equivalent-in-html)

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're after here, but does `\verbatim` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that \htmlonly does the trick